# Is it possible to have a cover over your chain,cassette,derailleur and cogs to avoid regular cleaning?

Tags: hybrid-bike

i was searching online for a product online but couldn't find anything.There are a lot of people creating new stuffs on crowd-funding projects like on kickstarter. I was wondering if if it is possible to have a cover on the derailleur system on a bicycle to avoid regular cleaning for the bike derailleurs,cassetes,chain,cogs

Comment: If you only ride in good weather and on asphalt, cleaning shouldn't be needed. Only infrequent lubricating of the chain.

Comment: It's impractical on the average derailleur-style bike.  Even if you could make one fit (and not interfere with the rear mech, it's not good to have a cover over the chain if the chain pops off for whatever reason.

Comment: A cover over the chain would also make it more difficult and time consuming to change a flat.  This is the whole reason we have quick release hubs. So that we can change tires quickly. For people who really care about low maintenance there are other solutions such as belt drives and internally geared hubs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its quite tricky with a derailleur geared bike, due to well, the derailleur having to move.

A common solution to this is either to:

1) Run single speed

2) Run an internal gear hub

Both options can be run with a chain case [image: chaincase]

which can cut down on some of the maintenance (but does make things like changing the flat or occasional lubrications a bit more annoying).

Belt drives can also be run in configurations (1),(2), and are supposed to have less maintenance, but you need a more special frame since belts cannot be cut to be installed.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I went with "internal gear hub" for my town commuting bike.

Comment: A nice side effect on a commuter is that you don't have to strap your pants so they don't get caught in the chain.

Comment: But fixing a flat on a bike with a fully-enclosed chain is a major PITA.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, I also had Schwalbe Marathon Plus on that bike...   (My ride to work was short enough that raw speed was not an issue.)

Comment: @Ian - In the case I experienced, on my son's bike, it was an IGH and we actually needed to change out a spoke, in part because the large-diameter IGH puts more stress on spokes and breaks them.  The problem was that the chain got off the front sprocket while we were working on it, and you have to remove the crank arm to remove the front part of the enclosure.  Finally monkeyed the chain back on, but it was a struggle.